# How to get the publishing state of a given page?

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, pnp-js

Currently I'm trying to get some information of the publishing state of a given page.

Maybe anybody has an idea for this issue.

Thanks in advance

To get information about the page I use pnpjs to retrieve the pages list item as follows:

```js
const itemOfPageEN = (await sp.web.getList(this._sitePagesUrl).items.getById(idOfPageEN))();
console.log(LOG_SOURCE, "itemOfPageEN", itemOfPageEN);
```

in `idOfPageEN` I provide the ID of a translated page, to get the corresponding item back.

In my console.log Output I can not find any attribute, which give me any information about the publishing state of the given page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item that is returned in your `itemOfPageEN` variable should have a property `OData__UIVersionString` that gives you the Major and the Minor version of the page, i.e. `0.1` or `1.0`.
If the Major version is `0`, then there is no published version of the page.
If the Major version is `1` or higher, then there is a published version of the page.

There are other endpoints available that give additional information about the publishing state of the page, for example the `versions` endpoint.
In REST you would add "versions" to the url of the list item that corresponds to the page, like `..._api/Web/Lists(guid'f8ee0b0f-2dd2-4a6b-ad21-6b1e61334d00')/Items(83)/versions`.

Then you get detailed information about all versions of the page, including the Moderation Status which corresponds to the Publishing state. It is in the `OData__x005f_ModerationStatus` property of the version with the highest version number. If it is 0, then the version is a published version.
The other possible values for the Moderation Status are:

| Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Approved |
| 1 | Denied |
| 2 | Pending |
| 3 | Draft |
| 4 | Scheduled |

Hth, Matthias